# Osclass subcategory listing sucess; item count fails

Tags: php, recursion, osclass

I need to print

// Main category
Classifieds (3)
 ->Books(2)
 ->DVD(1)

when Selecting Book(2)

it should print

Book(2)
->Children's Book(0)
->Chemistry(2)

It would be great if the sub->sub-> keep on going until the subcategory count ends.

I had coded it but fails to print the count in each category

```
$sid=osc_search_category_id();
              $this_cat= $sid[0];
              $categories = osc_get_categories() ; 
              foreach($categories as $cat) { 
              if($cat['pk_i_id']==$this_cat){
                if (count($cat['categories'])>0) {
                  foreach ($cat['categories'] as $sub) {
                    echo $sub['s_name'].'-'.osc_category_total_items();
                  }
                }
              } 
              }
```

This code is fits for any count of subcategory. **Only fails in item count**

Will a recursive function produce result?
the proposed output is 
[image]

IF someone who have a better logic can help me.
Thank You.

Comment: @edd Could you help me here

Answer (score 1):

Hi to get catégorie items number try this :

```
echo $sub['s_name'].'-'.$sub['i_num_items'];
```